# C++ Merge sort of linked list is not sorting the first two indices

Tags: c++, mergesort, singly-linked-list

I am getting a bit lost trying to figure out how to recursively merge sort my linked list. I have tried following some guides but I'm getting a bit lost with all the pointers and recursion. It feels like the problem is with the merge function once the lists have a single node each.

I have a `Node` class and a list class. I have left out other member functions to make it more readable. Here are the classes. Sorry some of the variable names aren't the best in the functions.

```
class Node {
  public:
    int val;
    Node *next;
};

class Linked_list {
  private:
    unsigned int length;
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
  public:
    void sort_ascending();
    void merge_sort(Node **);
    void halve(Node *&, Node *&, Node *&);
    Node* merge(Node *, Node *);
};
```

I start with `sort_ascending()` which creates a `Node` pointer and sets it to the first node in the list and then calls `merge_sort` with the pointer as a parameter.

```
void Linked_list::sort_ascending() {
    Node *h = head->next;
    merge_sort(&h);
}
```

`merge_sort` checks if the first two indices are `NULL`, returns if they are. Otherwise the linked list is halved.

```
void Linked_list::merge_sort(Node **h) {
    Node *t = *h;
    Node *a;
    Node *b;
    if ((t == NULL) || (t->next == NULL)) {
        return;
    }
    halve(t, a, b);
    merge_sort(&a);
    merge_sort(&b);
    *h = merge(a, b);
    return;
}
```

Here is the function for splitting the list in halves.

```
void Linked_list::halve(Node *&t, Node *&a, Node *&b) {
    Node *h1 = t;
    Node *h2 = t->next;
    while (h2 != NULL) {
        h2 = h2->next;
        if (h2 != NULL) {
            h1 = h1->next;
            h2 = h2->next;
        }
    }
    a = t;
    b = h1->next;
    h1->next = NULL;
}
```

Finally the merge function.

```
Node *Linked_list::merge(Node *a, Node *b) {
    Node *h = NULL;
    if (a == NULL) {
        return b;
    }
    if (b == NULL) {
        return a;
    }
    if (a->val <= b->val) {
        h = a;
        h->next = merge(a->next, b);
    } else {
        h = b;
        h->next = merge(a, b->next);
    }
    return h;
}
```

When I run my program and enter/print a few values I get:

```
9 4 32 2 6
```

Then when I sort it the output becomes:

```
9 4 2 6 32
```

Comment: These things can be tricky. Your input's already pretty small. Step through with your debugger to see where it's going wrong. You have this great tool at your disposal. Use it!

Comment: I haven't quite figured out the debugging thing. I'm using vim and it can be hard to gauge where a problem is. It sounds like visual studio is a popular choice. Would you recommend I try that out or something else in particular?

Comment: I use visual studio on my windows machine, and gdb on my linux machine at work. What's your OS? Windows? I feel like if you're using vim on windows you're in some kind of linux wrapper and probably have access to gdb?

Comment: Don't put off learning the debugger. It may seem like a waste of time. You may want to roll your eyes at it, but it's like the difference between learning to drive with a blindfold on and without (for clarify - using the debugger is analogous to NOT having a blindfold on).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here. I use ssh to login to our school's servers, which then uses vim. I'm on windows. Not sure what gdb is. Thanks by the way for responding!

Comment: No problem, we're all ignorant about many things at many different times. gdb is the GNU Debugger. My experience with it is primarily command line. If you're ssh'ing into your school computers, you're probably in a linux OS, operating in a bash shell. I thin the easier thing to do will be to install Visual Studio Community on your home PC or laptop, compile/run your code in that, and learn to use the debugger that comes with the VS IDE. gdb can be kind of archaic - it's primarily command line interface.

Comment: The main functionality you want out of a debugger is 1. the ability to set *breakpoints* which pause program operation, 2. the ability to step through code (usually one line at a time), and 3. the ability to inspect variables while paused at certain lines. The workflow is usually `look at variables of interest, single-step the program to the next line, look at variables, hey wait why did that change to that? that's not right. Found my bug!`

Comment: That sounds like it will speed things up a lot, I'll definitely check that out. So far I've been trying to draw out everything on paper to search for hiccups. Thanks for the suggestion and explanation!

Comment: Paper is the definitely the way to go to work out your algorithm. You get 15 million merits for writing up documentation ahead of time. Your debugger is the way to go to make sure your implementation matches that documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sortAscending function

```
void Linked_list::sort_ascending(){
   Node *h = head->next;
   merge_sort(&h);
}
```

See above that you are pointing node*h to next of head. Not head itself. And maybe thats why it excludes the first item i.e head itself while sorting the linked list.

Comment: Shoot you're right thanks. I forgot that head is the first node rather than pointing to the first node.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark the answer correct it if it works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Other reason than the one @VeryBhatti pointed out,

```
while(h2 != NULL){
    h2 = h2->next;
    if(h2 != NULL){
        h1 = h1->next;
        h2 = h2->next;
    }
}
```

I don't get the logic of your `halve` function. As the `h1` is also moving along `h2`, when the while statement breaks, the `h1` will always point at second to the last element instead of the center.

Why not use `length` variable to halve the list? Simplifying your code will significantly help you debug the code yourself.

Also, using both `reference` and `pointer` at the same time seems to be complicating your code. What I would recommend is to first try implementing it in `c` style instead of `cpp` style. Because you are using a linked list, you should be able to implement this without using pointer to a pointer.

Again, try to simplify your code as possible and look for other merge sort samples too.

Comment: I was trying to follow along with the "rabbit/hare" "slow/fast" method of splitting it up. But you make a good point. I'm a bit confused with it as well. I'll try to use the length instead. As for the references/pointers, it's all a bit confusing. I'll try and clean it up and simplify it. Thank you for your input, I have a great deal to learn!

Comment: The method posted using the slow and fast pointers is optimal, no need to change that. Conversely the `merge` function uses non-tail recursion to a depth proportional to the length of the list, which will cause a **stack overflow** for long lists.

Comment: @chqrlie Oh, I see. Sorry, my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.